# On hover change the background color of item in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have an angular app where ng-select is being used. On hover on an item in the drop, I want to change the background color of the value. How can I achieve this?
Here is my select:

```
<ng-select [items]="filters.areaOfExpertises" placeholder="Area of Expertise" (clear)="clearAOE()"
                   bindLabel="displayName" [(ngModel)]="filterBy.areaOfExpertise" (change)="onAOESelected($event)">
          <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
            <span class='display-name option-highlight' [ngOptionHighlight]="search" [title]="item.displayName">
              {{item.displayName}}
            </span>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-select>
```

I have tried a few things like:

1. This did not work

   .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option.ng-option-marked {
   background-color: #0E5981;
   }
2. This did not work

   .display-name ::ng-deep .ng-option.ng-option-marked{
   background-color: #0E5981;
   color: white;
   }
3. This did not work as expected. I was able to see the color on hover but not like I want it to be. See the snapshot. I want the entire row to be colored rather than just the text background.

   .display-name:hover{
   background-color: #0E5981;
   color: white;
   }

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working as follows:

```
::ng-deep .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option.ng-option-marked { background-color: #0E5981; }
```